# Адаптивная вёрстка с сохранением пропорций на bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, вёрстка

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с проблемой верстки вот такого компонента:

[image: Компонент]

Верстаю на bootstrap 4, такие требования для верстки.
Вопрос состоит в том, каким образом можно сверстать данный компонент так, чтобы сохранялись пропорции при изменении ширины компонента?
Т.е например оранжевый блок был всегда квадратным. 
На просторах интернета нарыл, что можно регулировать пропорции с помощью padding-bottom в процентах, но тогда придется все внутренние элементы позиционировать с помощью абсолютного позиционирования.
Не уверен, что такая схема является наиболее правильной. 
Может ли кто-нибудь из продвинутых верстальщиков поделиться своим опытом в даннос вопросе?
Спасибо большое заранее!

Answer (score 2):

Моё решение данной проблемы :

```css
.box {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  width: 13%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eaa206;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box--lg {
  width: 37%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.box--lg:before {
  padding-top: 34.33%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.content div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.num {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #eaa206;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.address span {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

.rate {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.rate span {
  font-size: 12px;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='box num'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div>
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='box box--lg name'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div>
      <span>Neighbor Boy<br> Painting LLC</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='box box--lg address'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div>
      <span>4343 Shallowford Rd<br> Suite B4-B<br> 
Marietta, GA 30062</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='box rate'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div>
      <span>Rating<br><span>5.0</span></span>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте задать размеры каждого блока в процентах, а не в статичных px. Или же в em + rem. **[Документация Гугл](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/responsive-design)**.